# How to clear form fields (input, textarea, select and radio) in javascript or jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have simple html form

```
 <form id="formreg" name="formreg" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:0; padding:0; float:left;" onsubmit="return CommonFunction(this);">   



  <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

  <tr>
  <td align="left"> First Name : </td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""/></td>
  </tr>



  <tr>
  <td align="left"> Last Name : </td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="lname" value=""/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="left"> Email : </td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="useremail" value=""/></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
  <td align="left"> Contact No : </td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="usercontact" value=""/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="left"> Designation : </td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="designation" value="" size="20" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="left"> Gender : </td>
  <td> 
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" /> Male &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" /> Female
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="left"> Country : </td>
  <td> 

  <select name="country">

     <option value="India">India</option>
     <option value="USA">USA</option>
     <option value="UK">UK</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  </tr>



  <tr>
  <td align="left"> Message/Comment: </td>
  <td> <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="left" colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="Sub" value="Insert" /> &nbsp; <input type="reset"  value="Reset" /> </td>
  </tr>

  </table>
  </form>
```

With form fields (input, text-area, select-box and radio button).

I need java-script function or jquery code to clear all form fields . I cannot use reset button because on form onsubmit event I'm calling a function called CommonFunction() which post all form fields using jQuery.ajax. The problem is when i submit the form data get posted successfully but the form fields doesnt clear automatically since I'm submitting form using jQuery.ajax

Once the data is submitted then i want form to be clear .

Need help

Comment: make a function, which clears the fields & call it in success event of ajax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that does just that. You can expand on this. But maybe using jQuery.forms would be better.

The fiddle resets values like the following. In your case you want to do this the callback success of the AJAX post.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     // Clear the form
     $('input[type=text], textarea').val('');
     $('select').find('option').prop("selected", false);
     $('input[type=radio]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

In the end you could make a helper function to store that code in. Then you can call it for other forms too and your code will be cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/TZ6GR/1/

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: You should avoid using `.removeAttr(...)`, but use `.prop(..., false)` instead. `.prop()` is designed specifically in jQuery with boolean attributes in mind (like `checked`, `disabled`, `selected`, `readonly` and the likes)

Comment: It does not affect performance, but it is the matter of using jQuery methods correctly. `.attr()` is known to be wonky in some browsers when dealing with boolean attributes. p/s: Also, do not use `.removeProp()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer #sidneydobber but in form onsubmit event im using javascript function which consist of $.ajax to post the form without reloading a page, so i cant able to use the above code...I need code which i can merge in my javascript function...so that when my form posted using $.ajax method it should automatically reset the form fields..Thanks.

Comment: You will use it in the succes callback function. The click() was just for illustration purposes. I'll make it more clear.

Comment: @GurunathaDogi, this works. (And should be marked as the correct answer). I was able to use this for a form I was submitting using AJAX. I was calling a function on form onsubmit and just threw the last 3 lines of sidneydobber's code in after the ajax stuff. i.e. function $someFunction() { $.ajax({ ajax stuff }); $('input[type=text].val(''); etc }. Worked a treat.

Comment: Thanks for asking to mark the answer correct @Luke! Glad it worked out for you too!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(function(){
   $("#formreg").find("input,textarea").val('');
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

After you've submitted the answers, you can run this line of code:

```
$("form#formreg").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
```

This will clear all the textfields and text inputs in the form.

Comment: But how to bring select box to original position and clear radio button from selected...